# WP7: How to Decompress an AES-256 Encrypted Zip File?

Tags: c#, security, windows-phone-7, aes, winzip

I am trying to decompress an `AES-256` encrypted zip file on Windows Phones 7 Application.
How can that be accomplished?

Is there anyway to port C++ libraries or so in the current version of WP7?
Any guide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Austin Salonen: i have not found anything yet but my research started from dotnetzip but it's not compatible with WP7 see: http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AES256 is very compute intensive, this is why AES128 and lower is recommended for embedded (i.e. phone) development. You could find out that it takes 3 to 2 seconds to decrypt even a relativly small file.

Furthermore because of the complexity involved in implementing the algo, examples might only be found in C (at which point you'll have to port it)

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/aes.aspx

If you have access to web services while the application is running, then you could always write a web service (using framework 3.5 or 4) that accepts the encrypted file and returns the unencrypted, yet still compresed file; but yes worse case is that you'll have to port your own. If you do port your own please upload it on codeplex so that future persons can benifit :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i will keep searching for any suitable library, and i might go with porting a C/C++ like Zip Archive, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't have the AES encryption requirement you could use [Silverlight SharpZipLib](http://slsharpziplib.codeplex.com/)

There doesn't appear to be anything currently available which support AES-256. You may have to look at porting something yourself

Comment: Thanks Matt, i will keep looking though.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use the BouncyCastle library on WP7 with just a couple small modifications as noted [here](http://awkwardcoder.blogspot.com/2011/08/using-bouncy-castle-on-windows-phone-7.html#!/2011/08/using-bouncy-castle-on-windows-phone-7.html).

Comment: And how does that help? Does BouncyCastle contain zip features? Or how do you suggest to add it to a zip library?